# react18 - Property 'xxx' does not exist on type 'unknown' in typescript

Tags: typescript, react-18

I have this `Globalcontext` which have value of `User`(string), `Loggingout`(function). I used to develop in `jsx` and I can just reference the context variable or function from any `React component` like below:

```
const {User, Loggingout} = useContext(Globalcontext)
```

But in my current project I have to use `tsx` because of some package. now I got the error:

> Property 'Loggingout' does not exist on type 'unknown'.

How can I resolve this?

**Edit 01**

below are my `Globalcontext` code:

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useContext } from 'react'

export const Globalcontext = createContext<{state: State; dispatch: Dispatch} | undefined>(undefined)

export function Globalprovider({ children: any }) {
  const [User, setuser] = useState<string>("John Doe")


  function Loggingout(){
    resetuser()
    ...
  }

...

  return (
    <Globalcontext.Provider value={{
        User,
        Loggingout,
    }}>
      {children}
    </Globalcontext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the `Globalcontext` declaration?

Comment: @InsalataCondita I added `Globalcontext` code in *Edit 01*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the type of your context value. Since you already have the Globalcontext exported, you can use that to define the type:

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useContext } from 'react';

interface GlobalContextType {
  User: string;
  Loggingout: () => void;
}

export const Globalcontext = createContext<GlobalContextType | undefined>(undefined);
```

In your component where you are using the context, you can specify the type of the context using the GlobalContextType:

```
const YourComponent = () => {
  const { User, Loggingout } = useContext(Globalcontext);


};
```